# Retain submitted data through refreshes

Tags: php, html

I want to retain `$orderby` and `$orderSort` (within the query) when I refresh the page or press the links at the bottom of the page to move to next page or previous page.

I have tried attaching `orderby` and `orderSort` to sessions but that didn't work due to the query - it always reverts back to Name and ASC from the else statement which seems like an issue with `isset($_POST['submit'])` but I have tried without it the same problem still occurs.

How do I retain my query (so long as the selections are not changed) as I go to the next page or previous page?

Top PHP portion:

```
//Next Page 
if (!isset($_GET['startrow']) or !is_numeric($_GET['startrow'])) {
 $startrow = 0;
} else {
$startrow = (int)$_GET['startrow'];
}
//when options are selected/submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
        if($_POST['select'] == "EventType")
        {
            $orderby = $_POST['select'];
            if($_POST['otherType'] != "Select an Event") {
            $EventType = 'WHERE `' . $orderby . '`="' . $_POST["otherType"] . '"';
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            $orderby = $_POST['select'];
        }
        $orderSort = $_POST['agree'];
    }
else
{
    $orderby = "Name";
    $orderSort = "ASC";
}

if ($stmt = $local->prepare("SELECT * FROM importdata $EventType ORDER BY `$orderby` $orderSort LIMIT     ?,10")) {
$stmt->bind_param('i', $startrow);
$stmt->execute();
$Recordset1 = $stmt->get_result();
$row_Recordset1 = $Recordset1->fetch_assoc();
$stmt->close();
}
```

Submit Form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="select">Order By:</label>
  <select name="select" id="selectType">
    <option value="EventType">Event</option>
    <option value=" Name"selected="selected">Race Name</option>
  </select> 
      <label><input type="radio" name="agree" value="ASC" checked>Ascend</label> 
    <label><input type="radio" name="agree" value="DESC">Descend</label>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Bottom PHP for next page/previous page

```
<?php
    $prev = $startrow - 10;
    if ($prev >= 0)
    echo '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8").'?startrow='.$prev.'">Previous </a>';
    echo '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8").'?startrow='.($startrow+10).'"> Next</a>';
?>
```

Comment: What was wrong with session variables? I think that's the de facto method of retaining settings on the server. Set the orderBy and orderSort session variables with each request, then if they aren't present in a request, use the session variables for the query.

Comment: try putting an if statement before the query --- if (!$_SESSION['orderby'] OR !$_SESSION['orderSort']) { ---.  this way it will only run if the session vars are NOT set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest something like this:

```
// Get our defaults for these variables.
$orderBy = isset($_SESSION['orderBy']) ? $_SESSION['orderBy'] : 'Name';
$orderSort = isset($_SESSION['orderSort']) ? $_SESSION['orderSort'] : 'ASC';

// When options are selected/submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($_POST['select'] == "EventType") {
        $orderby = $_POST['select'];

        if ($_POST['otherType'] != "Select an Event") {
            $EventType = 'WHERE `' . $orderby . '`="' . $_POST["otherType"] . '"';
        }
    } else {
        $orderby = $_POST['select'];
    }

    $orderSort = $_POST['agree'];

    // Set our session variables for next time when we set our defaults.
    $_SESSION['orderBy'] = $orderBy;
    $_SESSION['orderSort'] = $orderSort;
}
```

Comment: Perfect Mate! I was confused for a while but realized I didn't CamelCase orderBy like you did haha. Thank you :)

Comment: You're totally welcome! 90% of the time it's something small like that, haha.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write the parameters (`orderBy` and such) into every link, because HTTP is a stateless protocol. This is very tedious, so I suggest to look for a framework that does that for you.

Sessions should work too and for a simple application it might be an easier soultion. How exactly did you store the session variables?